# How to create a `span<std::byte>` from a single generic object?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a parameter of type `const T&` and want to turn it into `std::span<const std::byte>` or whatever the magic type that `std::as_bytes()` spits out is.

Ranges have a number of constructors, mostly aimed at containers, arrays, etc. But I can't seem to turn a single object into such a span. I feel like this is not an unreasonable thing to do.

EDIT: As an example, what **doesn't** compile:

```
const std::span<const std::byte> my_span(std::ranges::single_view{ object });
```

Comment: [`views::single`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/single_view)?

Comment: You probably need `std::span<const std::byte>` to preserve the constness.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @Galik good call, but still doesn't work for me. I'll edit in an example that doesn't compile

Comment: `std::ranges::single_view` should be *lvalue* like `std::as_bytes(std::span(single))`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 You deleted your answer, but just to be clear: `single_view` would produce a copy of the element wouldn't it?

Comment: @user17732522. Yes, `views::single` maybe is not a good workaround, since it *holds* a new value, returning a `span` will result in a dangling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointer to individual object can be treated the same way as pointer to an array of single object. You can create a span like this:

```
const T& t = value();
auto s = std::span<const T, 1>{std::addressof(t), 1};
```

You can then use `std::as_bytes`:

```
auto bytes = std::as_bytes(std::span<const T, 1>{std::addressof(t), 1});
```

Helper functions would probably be appropriate:

```
template<class T>
std::span<T, 1>
singular_span(T& t)
{
    return std::span<T, 1>{std::addressof(t), 1};
}

template<class T>
auto
singular_bytes(T& t)
{
    return std::as_bytes(singular_span(t));
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! But what overload of span does this trigger? The iterator one?

Comment: @Basti pointers are the archetypical iterators

Comment: @Caleth huh I guess so. But I got scared by the contiguous_iterator requirement on cppref. Well thanks again anyways

Answer (score 3):

You can `reinterpret_cast<std::byte *>` a pointer to any object, which gets you the first argument to the span, and the size of your type gives you the second.

```
template <typename T>
std::span<const std::byte, sizeof(T)> bytes_view(T & t) {
    return std::span<const std::byte, sizeof(T)> { reinterpret_cast<const std::byte *>(std::addressof(t)), sizeof(T) };
}

template <typename T>
requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
std::span<std::byte, sizeof(T)> mutable_bytes_view(T & t) {
    return std::span<std::byte, sizeof(T)> { reinterpret_cast<std::byte *>(std::addressof(t)), sizeof(T) };
}
```

Comment: `bytes_view()` should take a reference to a `const T`

Comment: @RemyLebeau this matches `std::as_bytes`, which adds const

Comment: It seems like you should `return std::span<...>{...};` instead of `return {...};`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 yep, thought the conditionally explicit constructor would be found :(